# Convert String to NSObject Swift 3

Tags: swift, string, swift3, nsdictionary, nsobject

Can anyone assist me with this problem? I'm getting this swift compiler error:

> 'Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected dictionary key type 'NSObject'

```
let orderParameters =

        ["customer": [     <- //Getting the error in this line
            "first_name": "Jon",
            "last_name":"Doe",
            "email": "john.doe@gmail.com"],
       "shipping": "free-shipping",
       "gateway": "dummy",
       "bill_to": [
            "first_name": "Jon",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "address_1": "123 Sunny Street",
            "address_2": "Sunnycreek",
            "city": "Sunnyvale",
            "county": "California",
            "country": "US",
            "postcode": "CA94040",
            "phone": "18768509132"],
            "ship_to": "bill_to"
        ] as [NSObject: AnyObject]
```

Do I insert ***as NSObject*** for the 'customer' parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `as [NSObject: AnyObject]`, write `as [AnyHashable: Any]`.

That is the Swift 3 way to express the general notion of a dictionary.

Comment: (Or, as Vadian says, omit it altogether.)

Answer (score 0):

Why unspecified `NSObject`? The keys are obviously all `String`.

In Swift 3 the unspecified value type of a dictionary is `Any`.

Make a type annotation

```
let orderParameters : [String:Any] = ...
```

and delete the type cast at the end